# Where can I ask Career-Development questions on the Stack Exchange about Programming? (without getting closed!)

Tags: support, site-rec

Every Career-Development question gets closed, This is pathetic! Where else am I meant to ask the question about programming.

It is pretty silly considering it is a guideline:

> What language should I learn next?
>   (Unless you have a specific
>   requirement and don't know which
>   language meets that requirement.) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

Although these tags are available and used on this programmers site?

[career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) [career-advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice) [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) [career-guidance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-guidance)

Comment: Rather than ranting and posting even more off-topic questions such as this one, why don't you take a look through those tags at the ones that have remained open to find out how to word a question that is **on-topic**?

Comment: OK fair enough. It's just that a lot of people ask these questions and they just get closed, Whats the point of that, Why don't they just migrate them somewhere.

Comment: migrate them where?

Comment: Let the moderators decide, they close them.

Comment: @Josh: And if none of the existing SE sites are on-topic for that question?

Comment: @Josh I suggest you head to http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com.  If after searching you don't find the answer to your question ("why don't they migrate them"), it is the perfect place to ask.  The comments here are too short to explain how off-topic questions can harm a community.  Also, check out http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: CareerOverflow.com or better still create "careers.programmers.com"?

Comment: @Josh: How much audience would a hypothetical "careers.programmers.com" site have? If there are only 5 people answering questions on a site, then it's not really going to be that helpful to anyone. That said, if you feel it would be useful (and not made redundant by another site), feel free to propose it on Area51 and see if it gets enough interested people.

Comment: Ok, So your basically saying. "Nobody should be asking these questions".

Comment: No that is not what anyone is saying. Question relating to career's are valid if asked in the right the context. Asking questions that only pertain to your specific situation are not useful to the community. Questions that have no legitimate answer are also not useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c)

Answer (score 5):

The answer to "what language should I learn next" is almost always either "it depends" or "it doesn't matter. just pick one." The "specific requirement" part of the guideline is meant to address situations like not knowing what language to choose for a particular kind of problem. For example, I want to get into robotics -- what language(s) should I focus on first?

Saying that your current career situation is a specific requirement may fit the letter of the guideline but may also be going against its spirit.

Career development questions that are general enough to apply to a wider audience are still welcome on Programmers.SE.

Comment: I thought it applied to a wider audience considering I got 4 answers before the moderators quickly closed it.. If you left it open or asked me what I could add to make it more specific, It would get a wider audience. But I thought it was pretty specific what I was asking.

Comment: @Josh Your question read to me like the answer would be a classic "it depends". You got a few answers to your question but they aren't likely to be useful to anybody else who is not in your situation. As a counter-example, here's a question that I think fits the "specific requirement" guideline: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/48442/markup-language-with-pdf-output.

Answer (score 4):

The question "What language to Learn Next?" and all the various derivatives of that same question has been answered countless times, both by the volunteers on this site, as well as the authors of numerous blogs, articles, career journals, and forums.

In fact, here is the same question [What Should I Learn Next?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33964/what-should-i-learn-next).  There are 8 answers there about what language to learn next.

[This Programmers SE Search for "What Language Should I Learn"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+language+should+i+learn) turns up 67 pages of results, with the first 2 pages dedicated to various different incarnations of the question `What Language Should I Learn Next?`

Thus, if you want to know the answer to that question.  Start there and work your way through the bounty of answers available.  In addition to answers, you'll find links to other resources, which will link to other forums, documents, opinions, articles, and journals.

The goal is to not answer the same questions that have already been answered; instead, the volunteers here look forward to challenging new questions that have yet to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

[CareerOverflow.com](http://careeroverflow.com/) would be my suggestion though I'm not sure how active is that site.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "the question about programming"? If you look at the not-closed questions on Programmers.SE, then you'll see a wide variety of different questions related to programming.

Note that the example from the FAQ you cite is *specifically listed as **off-topic*** for this site - so you shouldn't be surprised if questions of that nature get closed.

If you want examples of career-development questions that *are* on topic, take a look at the other questions that get tagged as such for examples of questions that *do* belong here.

Finally, questions about Programmers.SE itself belong on the Meta site, not directly here.

Comment: Ok, Im new around here. Still think you should migrate them somewhere not just close them. There is no such thing as a stupid question. To many rules, I just want to ask a question that is really important to me. I'll read the FAQ but it is very strict on what your allowed to ask, when your asking about a important topic like career-development.

Comment: @Josh: The problem really is that you asking for career advice has little (if any) relevance to anyone who comes along later. Stack Overflow (and all the other StackExchange sites) are not just about answering questions (any forum can do that), they're also about providing a reference so that the next person coming along doesn't need to even ask, they just have a valid, working answer right there.

Comment: @Josh: If you think there's no such thing as a stupid question you are sorely mistaken. Also, what's the point in asking a question if it's in the wrong place and nobody that could organize it is seeing it? Clearly there is a need for organization or we're all wasting our time in a busy noise to signal ratio.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing: You should have posted this question here: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/

For another, "career-development" is very ambiguous. You asking the questions wrong. Decide what you want to do first, then come back and ask us how to get there.