# I have made an observation, can i ask about the cause?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I am currently trying to figure out how it is possible that nearly all of our 2D software vector graphics engines exhibit a flaw. This flaw is known and we know how to circumvent it, there is even a mathematical proof for this. Most 3D Rendering engines be they real time or not, GPU accelerated or not, do not generally exhibit this problem.

So what i would like to know is: *what the cause of this is?*

Is this a suitable question or is the answer too subjective and open for speculation? (and how can i know before asking) And is it within scope?

I my mind this is about:

- software development methods and practices

And how they differ in these disciplines. But maybe this is about how we teach this stuff?

Answer (score 5):

This question may be on-topic as a software design question, not a software development methods and practices question. The [Help Center's on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) provides links to Wikipedia to define these terms - methods and practices refers to methods like sequential development, the agile methods, Lean, and CMMI and practices refers to things like Test Driven Development, Domain Driven Design. Software design includes identifying and selecting data structures and algorithms, along with a number of other topics.

Although it's likely to be on-topic, I'm not sure you'll get a good answer here because of the core audience of this community. We are "professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle who care about creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly". We may not have the depth of experience in graphics engines or mathematics to provide a suitable answer to your question. We maintain [a list of other Stack Exchange sites that cover topics related to software development](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8066/4), some of which may be on-topic here but they provide a different set of experiences.

You should read their Help Center and search before asking a question, but it looks like [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) may be good fits for your question. Don't forget that cross-posting is not acceptable on the Stack Exchange network, so be sure to tailor your question for the specific audience to receive the best answers from that given community.

Comment: Yes i know about this, i considered Computer Science but thought this would be better due to a previous suggestion. Signal processing is otherwise good, except that the probelm lies in severe lack of sgnal processing skill.

Comment: But maybe your right teaching belongs to Computer Science, but then again why they would choose such things is not science. I am in a bind here so i dont know what bin i should put this in as its hafway in many.

Comment: @joojaa You need to ask this where you think the experts are. I don't think that's here - we're experts in building software systems, not graphics engines and algorithms. You can always ask on the other site's Metas to get their take as well.

Comment: Yes but this is a question of using an obsolete algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: we have lots of experts on algorithms here, too. I would recommend the OP he should give it a try and if we see the topic really fits better on CS or gamedev.stackexchange.com or elsewhere, we can still recommend for migration.

Comment: @DocBrown I don't doubt that we do have algorithm experts here. However, it's not the primary focus. I would highly recommend looking at CS as a first start for graphics and vision algorithm questions, which this appears to be. They would be more likely to have an expert who knows why this faulty algorithm was chosen over other algorithms, for example.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: we are moving in the dark without knowing the actual question. And just because "algorithms" did not make it into the famous four bullet points, we had consensus that "algorithms" is still on-topic as part of software design, AFAIK?

Comment: [ComputerGraphics.SE] is also a strong candidate, @joojaa.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, algorithms is part of software design. Like I said in my answer, the question is likely on-topic. It's a matter of finding where the best people to answer the question are, and I don't think that's here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell well no if i could ask this on computer graphics i would but i know what their answer would be since i most likely would have to answer it myself.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I think your right, however my intention is not really to validate whether or not there is a flaw, i know ot exists. I know how to circumvent it in ALL possible cases (another thing is how expensive it is). This is not really my problem, my problem is why do not programmers do searches in the state of the art before they begin. But basically i got the answer which basically came down to "It worked why improve on it", which is a bit stupid. Maybe i asked it the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

This might depend on the nature of the flaw. If you expect the reason to be in the specific implementation of a specific 2D vector graphics engine, you should better ask in the support forum of the engine. If you have no clue if this is caused by the specific implementation of that engine, or if there is a more general reason behind it, caused by the typical 2D algorithms used in those engines (indicated by the fact you observed the same flaw in different engines), you can ask exactly that here on "Programmers".

Just make sure readers won't interpret your question as a tool specific, or implementation dependend question, or as a question which leads to "wild guessing".

Comment: No, i know why this flaw exists and i know how to get rid of it.  It is a flaw that exists in all 3 adobes main engines, all browsere SVG platforms, all PDF readers save one, all main GUI rendering toolkits including QT and so on... But the same problem is mostly absent in 3D Graphics

Comment: @joojaa: well, ask your question and let us see what happens. What is the worst thing which could happen? You might get some downvotes and the question could be closed - is that really such a problem? If that will be the outcome, just don't take it personal.

Comment: No its not i was just trying to find a home for a question that nastily lies just on the edge of so many SO sites

Comment: @joojaa: ask your question, and if you get some comments it might fit better elsewhere, consider to flag your question for migration.

Comment: Done! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/332068/coverage-flaw-in-the-algorithm-how-to-get-rid-of-its-use I might have done some work to make the question less ranty i must confess im running out of time i might return on it later.