# Where can I ask a subjective programming question?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to programming and have a lot of questions regarding best practices and suggested tools.  I used to try to ask these questions on Stackoverflow but they were always downvoted and closed.  What is the appropriate forum to ask such questions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site can be used to ask questions about best practices so long as your questions are specific. You can ask about suggested tools on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: here is fine, go for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c)

Comment: Start with published practices; many organizations publish their practices.  many languages have published coding standards, tools documentation may include recommendation.  If you have specific questions, try asking in a form that does not solicit opinions.

Answer (score 4):

[I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c) lists a number of Stack Exchange sites that are related to software development, some more closely than others. However, none of them accept overly subjective questions. Subjective questions in general just aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format.

There are other communities of software developers out there. Reddit has several subreddits related to programming, computer science, software engineering, and IT, but you'll need to check each community's rules for what to post. [Dev.to](https://dev.to/) is a pretty robust community, too. There may be others, too.

Comment: If OP is looking specifically for a Q&A style site that accepts subjective questions, [Quora](https://www.quora.com) is probably the best known.