# Can I ask here the Qn about technology comparison here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, tags, vote-to-close

Today I asked [this Qn](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/356443/24410), but got downvoted and about to close:

> ### Are there any comparison for Qt vs .Net core for server development?
>
> We want to build a server which can be scalable for future purpose.
> With availability of good developers in C++ & C# both, we were
> wondering which technology to choose if we want to make a good
> performance http/TCP server availabile in all major platforms?
>
> Couldn't find any comparison among them in internet. Would be
> interested in pro-con or comparison between these 2 platforms, without
> forming opinion.

Was my Qn wrongly framed or it doesn't belong to this site?
Where can I ask it in SE network?

Comment: see also: [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8066/31260)

Comment: I recommend to have a look into the "Too broad" section of this meta question: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490