# Where can you ask questions about certificates?

Tags: discussion

Where can you ask questions about software certificates? When I post something about certificates, my post here, will be deleted after 2 minutes. Can you recommend a website for programmers like me, who want to study programming by themself? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a [list of other Stack Exchange sites that have content that may be of interest to users here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c). However, none of them seem to allow questions about education and career development. There are a number of other forums and communities out there, but we don't maintain a comprehensive list of their rules and topics - you'll have to seek them out on your own. There may be good subreddits on Reddit or other forums.