# Is the "internship" tag still of any use?

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions with the [internship](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/internship/info) tag are typically about career advice, which is off-topic. Most of the [28 questions currently tagged with that label](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internship) got closed for this reason. I actually cannot imagine any on-topic question which deserves this tag.

So can we delete/cleanup the tag? At least a "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" warning seems to be appropriate. Or even better, a text which makes it clear askers are not just expected to avoid the tag, but to avoid asking such questions.

Ok, in between I got 6 upvotes, but no answer. So I made an attempt to fix the tag description a little bit. To anyone who has enough rep, feel free to improve the description even more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DO NOT USE THIS TAG!

Internship questions seeking career advice are off-topic on this site. We recommend avoiding asking any such questions here. Before going elsewhere please review their [rules](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/131624).

Comment: I also think if we're discouraging the use of the tag the following text can be removed:
An internship is a job where the employee is generally considered new to the company's business domain and processes. These jobs can be paid or volunteer and full-time or part-time. Internships are often filled by students or individuals looking primarily to develop experience. Internships can but do not always lead to a permanent job with the host company.

Comment: Yep, that's what I had in mind, but I did not want to make such a radical change without a second pair of eyes. I streamlined the text a little bit more, feel free to review it now.

Comment: @DocBrown even better. A hint of what to do with a heavy dose of how to do it right.