# How can I ask this question better?

Tags: discussion, questions

I really tried to write this question in such a way that it was not a shopping question. I've been using stackoverflow and similar sites for a long time and know why shopping questions and opinion questions are frowned upon - I respect and agree with that stance. In this case I am looking for information about a pattern or type of design that I might not be aware of yet, so that I continue to research tools on my own. Is this this question salvageable? If so, I would very much appreciate advice on how to fix it or where I should take my question instead.

[Is a serverless architecture with users and user-created data possible yet?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/392979/is-a-serverless-architecture-with-users-and-user-created-data-possible-yet)

Comment: ...see also [On the troubles of naming and terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6583/31260)

Comment: I think the marked questions correctly address my question, but I am a bit disappointed that you really can't ask about feasibility of design ideas on this site. Any recommendations for sites that are more oriented to those questions? Thanks @gnat for your time.

Comment: see [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/31260)

Comment: @gnat thank you