# Can you help me in finding a way to phrase or a community where I can have an answer to the following question?

Tags: discussion, support

> We are often building and testing new file formats. We are looking for
>   a list of features and standard figure of merits of a file format for
>   comparison and evaluation. For instance, writing and reading speed,
>   compression, the possibility of chunking the memory, readability.
>
> We are aware that each file formats is built for a specific purpose
>   and that some features might not be always a pro or a cons.
>   Nevertheless, we would like to know if there is any ISO, controlled
>   vocabulary or testing suite for an objective and standardized
>   evaluation of file formats.

I posted it here but I was downvoted without any feedback. Can you help me in finding the right community to ask this important question for my job?
I know it's a finite set of feature and it could fit the software engineering if rephrase. I am aware of other websites but I don't understand how can I rephrase it.

Comment: 10k+: [link to original](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/397105/what-are-the-standard-key-performance-indexes-and-features-of-a-file-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

Comment: ...see also [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be off put by a couple of downvotes. But I don't think you will get an answer to your question here.

The problem is that it's basically a "do my research" question. It can only be answered by someone who just happens to have had the same problem as you, already did the same research, knows the answer and is willing to share.

Everyone else doesn't know and so would just have to do the same things you are presumably doing, googling, reading articles, making calls, emailing questions off, testing theories etc etc.

It's a lot of work for internet points and presumably you are being paid to do it.

Some people will downvote just because they don't know. Some people will be offended that you are asking them to do something they think you should be doing and downvote because of that.

It's just human nature and won't affect the answer you get if the 1 person who happens to know the answer sees your question.

You could probably rephrase your question to avoid the two pitfalls of

1. asking for recommended resource. ie website/book/tool that defines file format testing
2. asking for list of pros and cons of different file formats

But I think it's still a low probability you will get a useful answer. There's a high probability that there is no ISO standard for file format feature comparison at all.

Comment: Thanks for answer me, I am actually a PhD student, I thought was a good question because of limited set of feature a file format can have. By the way, because nobody was able to answer I think at least it's not a trivial one so this is good to know.