# Is code review a thing here?

Tags: support

I am working on a project with some architectural challanges, some of which are not known by my colleagues. Therefore, I'd like experienced people take a look on my code (just the frontend) so I can have a bit of guidance to where I am going and if I am going to the right path. Is there any way I can ask for code review and, if so, what information I need to provide, I mean, should I have a `readme` file at every folder explaining a bit of the decisions I took for the files contained there or is that too far and I should maybe let people take a look by themselves. Or, I can, maybe, describe all my code in one question, with text and actual code (but that seems like it'll end up being a gigantic question)?

Comment: You might be interested in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Yup. I am interested in that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-software-engineering-where-else-c)